# postgresql java This ResultSet is closed exception

Tags: java, postgresql, resultset

I'm trying to access a postgresql DB from Java. i'm having some issues with the ResultSet, and I can't figure out why

This is the method that calls the DB. the exception is thrown when trying to access the while(rs.next())

```
public Usuario buscarUsuario(String nombre){

    String sql = "SELECT * from usuario WHERE nombre_usuario = '"+nombre+"'";

    BaseDeDatos.getInstancia().establecerConexion();
    ResultSet rs = BaseDeDatos.getInstancia().ejecutarQuery(sql);

    Usuario us= new Usuario();
    try {
        while(rs.next()){
            us.setNombreUsuario(rs.getObject(1).toString());
            us.setContrasena(rs.getObject(2).toString());
            us.setActivo(rs.getBoolean(3));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BaseDeDatos.getInstancia().cerrarConexion();

    return us;

}
```

this is what BaseDeDatos.getInstancia().ejecutarQuery(sql) does

```
 public ResultSet ejecutarQuery(String sql){
    try{
        stmt = conexion.createStatement();
        rsst=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        stmt.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return rsst;
}
```

the exception:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2852)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.next(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1890)
    at com.CBTD.database.TablaUsuario.buscarUsuario(TablaUsuario.java:20)
    at com.CBTD.logica.LoginExpert.validarUsuario(LoginExpert.java:11)
    at com.CBTD.logica.prueba.main(prueba.java:40)

I've been searching all over the internet, and I can't find an answer. it's driving me crazy. Please, any piece of help will be useful.

Comment: Probably because you closed connection in `ejecutarQuery` method.

Comment: What's this `BaseDeDatos.getInstancia(),ejecutarQuery()` doing? Does it use the same `Statement` instead for multiple threads? Does it use the same `Connection` instance for multiple threads?

Comment: You may want to post the exception.

Comment: thanks folks!! Branislav Lazic was right =S really apreciate the help